# Скрол страницы, изменение высоты дива

Tags: jquery, javascript, css

Как на jquery реализовать такую штуку:
У меня есть див, которому присвоен класс header, он имеет высоту в 140 символов, нужно, что бы когда человек начал пролистывать страницу, размер хедера плавно поменялся на 40 пикселей.

Если я пишу в консоли

```
 $(".head_main").css("height", "40px");
```

То хедер уменьшается до 40 пикселей, но если я пишу в консоль уже что-то типо такого:

```
$("#body").scroll( function() {
var value = $(this).scrollTop();
if ( value > 100 )
    $(".head_main").css("height", "40px");
});
```

То ничего не происходит, в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: сорри за вопрос, а зачем вы это в консоли пишете? тяжелее отлаживать ведь.  
пример на jsfiddle.net киньте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, `$(".head_main").css("height", "40px")` не обеспечит плавную анимацию. Используйте [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Во-вторых, подозреваю что вы неправильно написали селектор. У вас действительно есть тег с `id="body"`? Если хотите выбрать `<body>`, то нужно писать так:

```
$("body").scroll( function( ... ) {} )
```